# Passing variables to two activities with an intent

Tags: java, android

I want to pass some double Values from my main Activity (I get them via an EditText-field) to two other classes. Every time I´ll try to run the App I get a Error-Message (illegal start of type /  expected). Can someone explain these to me? Can someone tell me how I can pass them from Main_Activity to Main2Activity and to the achtmalacht - Activity?

Here is the code I have:

Main Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Button weiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter);
            weiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    EditText EingabeBreite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.breite);
                    EditText EingabeHohe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.höhe);
                    EditText EingabeLange = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.länge);


                    double breite = Double.parseDouble(EingabeBreite.getText().toString());
                    double hohe = Double.parseDouble(EingabeHohe.getText().toString());
                    double lange = Double.parseDouble(EingabeLange.getText().toString());


                    Intent rüberin2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                    rüberin2.putExtra("breite", breite);
                    rüberin2.putExtra("höhe", hohe);
                    rüberin2.putExtra("länge", lange);

                    startActivity(rüberin2);


                }
            });

        }}
```

Main2Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        TextView frequenz4x4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viermalvier);
        TextView frequenz6x6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sechsmalsechs);
        TextView frequenz8x8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.achtmalacht);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        double G4 = extras.getDouble("breite");
        double G5 = extras.getDouble("höhe");
        double G3 = extras.getDouble("länge");

        final double breite = G4;
        final double hohe = G5;
        final double lange = G3;

        double f4 = 344 / 2 / G3;
        TextView Frequenz4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viermalvier);
        Frequenz4.setText(Double.toString((f4)));

        double f6 = 344 / 2 / G4;
        TextView Frequenz6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sechsmalsechs);
        Frequenz6.setText(Double.toString((f6)));

        double f8 = 344 / 2 / G5;
        TextView Frequenz8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.achtmalacht);
        Frequenz8.setText(Double.toString((f6)));


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent rüberin8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                rüberin8.putExtra("breite", breite);
                rüberin8.putExtra("höhe", hohe);
                rüberin8.putExtra("länge", lange);

                startActivity(rüberin8);




        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, why don't you use a class? You could store everything you want. Could it be a solution for you?

Comment: If this is not a solution, maybe the problem is that you don't use extras as bundle when passing the extras, but trying to get one in the next activity. Try in the first to put your variable in a bundle, then pass this bundle as extra.

Comment: you don't attach a `Bundle` in the first snippet, that's why the `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` in the second snippet returns an empty bundle which doesn't contain the values you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted it appears as if you have one "}" curly bracket too many at the end of you `onCreate()` method. But since you are only providing a part of the code, this could just be a copy/paste error from when you posted the question.

If that doesn't fix the problem consider this:

In your `Main2Activity` code try to use this instead:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double G4 = intent.getDoubleExtra("breite", -1.0);
double G5 = intent.getDoubleExtra("höhe", -1.0);
double G3 = intent.getDoubleExtra("länge", -1.0);
```

This way you can set a default value for comparison.

You might also be having issues with the conversion to `double`. I assume the problem is your device settings. I take it from your code that is being run on a device that is set to a German environment.

You will need to change the comma "," decimal to a point "." decimal separator before using `parseDouble`

```
String sBreite = EingabeBreite.getText().toString();
sBreite = sBreite.replace(",",".");
Double dBreite = Double.parseDouble(sBreite);
```